# What's an easy way to view formatted Markdown files?

Tags: markdown

When I tap spacebar on a `.markdown` file in the finder, Quick Look shows me a very nicely formatted view of that file. But the view doesn't act like a normal window, I can't select text from it, etc. All the apps I have that can open Markdown files show them in edit mode, without the pretty formatting.

Short of buying an app like [Marked](http://marked2app.com), is there some way to open Markdown files with pretty formatting?

Comment: You should be using a search engine before posting a question. Googling "os x markdown viewer" gives the _possible duplicate_ and MacDown as the top hits.

Comment: I searched quite a bit. MacDown seems clunky. I searched this site but with the term "markdown" not "md". Searching for "markdown preview" doesn't work. On well!

Comment: Have a look at: [Best Markdown Editors for OS X](https://www.raywenderlich.com/119949/top-five-markdown-editors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MacDown](http://macdown.uranusjr.com) is a free and open source markdown editor (and viewer). There are others out there as well. Try googling for markdown editors for more options.